# Reading value from XML file Throws an error - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data, f#-fake

I am trying to read value from XML file from FAKE , But I am getting an error i.e.

```
.fsx(9,16) : eror FS000: Incomplete structurd construct at or before this
 point in expression. Expected '->' or other token.
```

Below is my code , I am using `XMLHelper.XMLRead` to read values from xml file .

```
#r "./packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
open Fake.XMLHelper
Target "BuildMain" (fun _ ->
    for s in XMLHelper.XMLRead true "D:/test/Version.Config" "/version/major/minor"
        trace s)
"BuildMain"
RunTargetOrDefault "BuildMain"
```

Below is my XML File :

```
<version>
  <major number="2">
    <minor>1</minor>
    <build>1</build>
    <revised>1</revised>
  </major>
</version>
```

Here I am trying to read value from minor version , and moreover can I store this value in a variable so that I can use this later ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for ... in` construct requires either `do` or an arrow `->` before the body:

```
for s in XMLHelper.XMLRead true "D:/test/Version.Config" "/version/major/minor" do
    trace s
```

You use `do` if the body is another loop or just side-effecting code, as in:

```
for x in 1..5 do
   printfn "%d" x
```

You use arrow `->` to have the body produce a value, which then becomes part of the resulting list or sequence, as in:

```
let evenNumbers2to10 = [for x in 1..5 -> x*2]
```

The arrow `->` can be viewed as a shortcut for `do yield`:

```
let evenNumbers2to10 = [for x in 1..5 do yield x*2]
```

Comment: I m doing trace s in for loop as you mentioned , but I am getting an error i.e. The type '(string -> string ->seq<string>)' is not a type whose value can be enumerated with this syantax , i.e. is not compatible with either seq<_>,IEnumerable<_> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method

Comment: The [`XMLRead`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/XMLHelper.fs#L14-14) function has two more parameters.

Comment: Yes , and now It is working .. Thank you for your efforts :)