# Reading Xml file throws an error - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data, f#-fake

I am reading XML File in FAKE script using `XMLHelper.XMLRead` but it is throwing an error i.e.

`The type '(string -> string ->seq<string>)' is not a type whose value can be enumerated with this syantax , i.e. is not compatible with either seq<_>,IEnumerable<_> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method`

Below Is my code :

```
let x = XMLHelper.XMLRead true "D:/test/Version.Config" "/version/major/minor" 
Target "New" (fun _ ->
    for i in x do
        printf "%s" i
)
```

Comment: You're getting back a partially applied function and trying to enumerate it. You probably need more parameters for XMLRead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [API documentation for `XMLHelper`](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-xmlhelper.html), you'll see that the function signature for `XMLRead` looks like this:

```
failOnError:bool -> xmlFileName:string -> nameSpace:string -> prefix:string -> xPath:string -> seq<string>
```

It looks like you're specifying the `failOnError`, `xmlFileName` and `nameSpace` parameters*, but you didn't specify the last two string parameters. Since F# uses [partial application](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/), that means that what you're getting back from your `XMLRead` invocation is a function that is waiting for two more string parameters (hence the `string -> string -> (result)` function signature in the error message you got).

* You probably intended for `"/version/major/minor"` to fill the `xPath` parameter, but F# applies parameters in the order given, so it filled the third parameter, which was `nameSpace`.

To fix this, specify all the parameters that `XMLRead` expects. I've looked at the XMLRead source, and the `nameSpace` and `prefix` parameters should be empty strings if you're not using XML namespaces in your input document. So what you want is:

```
let x = XMLHelper.XMLRead true "D:/test/Version.Config" "" "" "/version/major/minor" 
Target "New" (fun _ ->
    for i in x do
        printf "%s" i
)
```

BTW, now that I've looked at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918450/reading-value-from-xml-file-throws-an-error-fake-fmake), I think you'll want the `XMLHelper.XMLRead_Int` function:

```
let minorVersion =
    match XMLHelper.XMLRead_Int true "D:/test/Version.Config" "" "" "/version/major/minor" with
    | true, v -> v
    | false, _ -> failwith "Minor version should have been an int"
```

Once your code gets past that line, either you have an int in `minorVersion`, or your build script has thrown an error and exited so that you can fix your `Version.Config` file.

Comment: Thank you rmunn :)